# Hoping that a regex can do this. Fixing broken XML

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a large XML file that I now want to parse.  The XML is fundamentally broken, and with over 2000 lines, I'm trying to avoid a hand cranked fix ;)

Can I use regex replace in Notepad++ to do this?

```
<Sensor ID="21.1.1_L"/>
```

to

```
<Sensor ID="21.1.1_L">
```

losing the tag close slash in all "Sensor" tags (and bearing in mind that I cannot simply replace /> with > and the ID is variable, including it's length and may or may not have the trailing underscore and alpha).

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work: Search for

```
(<Sensor [^<>]*)/>
```

and replace all with

```
\1>
```

`[^<>]*` will match any number of characters except angle brackets (this is to make sure that we can never match across a tag's boundary). Then, `/>` matches only if the current tag ends with a slash.

You will need to turn on regex matching in Notepad++, of course.

Comment: Wow!  I'm off to decode that regex sequence, worked a champ.  938 replacements quick as I could blink.  Thanks!!!